# How can I understand the use of query parameter in REST api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, rest

As a learner, I am trying to call the rest api. For example, you can see and copy the url from api provider as they listed on that link page.

https://docs.api.jikan.moe/#tag/top/operation/getTopAnime

```
function App() {
  const [topAnime, SetTopAnime] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://api.jikan.moe/v4/top/anime`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        SetTopAnime(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      });
  }, []);
```

But the question is; this does not let me to call a specific data I want to call.

To do that, I need to add some query parameters as api page written for developer.

Now, I see several examples that someone set it as follows:

```
  const getData = () => {
    axios
      **.get(`${apiTop}?sfw=true&limit=20`)**
      .then((res) => {
        return setData(res.data.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

that .get method and following code makes sense. But how that developer who coded that line knew '?sfw=true&' such thing?

If I don't understand this; what topic could be the one I should review then? I believe I understand what promises and fetch are, but not sure focusing on 'query parameter' is the right thing to solve my problem.

tl;dr
To call a specific data from getTopAnime, how should I set query parameters? (with my understanding, https://api.jikan.moe/v4/top/anime/type/movie
or
https://api.jikan.moe/v4/top/anime?=query/type/movie
is the limit to expand the thoughts.

Thanks...

Comment: To know what query parameters to use, you have to understand the API and know what parameters it will take and what parameters are needed for your objective.  This comes either from documentation for the API or in studying the code for that API or in reverse engineering what other clients are using.

Comment: Thank you. Come to think of it, these were not alien or expert level. It was just "if sfw is equal to true, and limit it to 20 query to call it'. Guess I thought too much...

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of the API -- https://docs.api.jikan.moe/

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There must be API documentation where you can read about these URI structures.

Though a real REST service sends you hyperlinks with URIs or URI templates which you follow, so you need to know what type of hyperlink watch for and the service gives you the URI structure. This is called HATEOAS constraint.